# How to remove degradation in voltage gain when replacing the original \$R_L\$ with a small value resistor?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt

For the following common-emitter amplifier, the original \$R_L = 4.7\space kΩ\$. When I replace it with a small value resistor (\$100\spaceΩ\$), the voltage gain will drop. Is there any way to drive the new low-impedance load without causing the degradation in the voltage gain?

---

**Circuit Diagram**

[image: Circuit Diagram]

---

**SetUp Details**

\$
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_G=600\space Ω \\
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_1=82\space kΩ \\
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_2=15\space kΩ \\
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_C=4.7\space kΩ\\
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_E=910\space Ω \\
\space \space \space \space \space \space \space \space R_L=4.7\space kΩ
\$

---

*Thank you for your help.*

Comment: Recalculate and redesign for the new operating point with the new load.

Comment: Or add a buffer stage to the output.

Comment: Add an emitter follower (comon collector) or a full push pull stage.

Answer (score 1):

Your output resistance is mostly controlled by Rc, which is 4.7k, so you are going to get a lot of loss driving such a small load resistance. To maintain gain and drive the low resistance you need a common collector buffer, as Photon said.

Comment: How to integrate the common-collector buffer into the circuit? Thank you.